# Angular2 auto scroll div to bottom - Expression changed exception

Tags: angular

I have a div with `overflow-y: scroll;` that is populated by an `Observable.interval()` polling and basic `{{content}}` interpolation.
I'm trying to have it automatically scrolled to the bottom, so the last line will always be visible.
I found this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/7yz2DUttPjI5GVJkvr5h?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts which looks like the most elegant solution:
`<div #list class="list" [scrollTop]="list.scrollHeight">`
However when I try the same approach I get a `Expression has changed after it was checked.` Exception.

```
<div class="cdiv" #cdiv [scrollTop]="cdiv.scrollHeight">{{content}}</div>
```

I can only assume that the `*ngFor .. | async` from the plunker behaves differently internally than the direct interpolation I'm using.
However I don't understand exactly why and if there is a way to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the most elegant solution in Angular:

Assign a variable to the div element that you want to scroll:

```
<div class="chat-messages" #container> <!-- Your content --> </div>
```

View the div in your Controller and call the `scrollToBottom` method if you update the content of your container:

```
export class ChatComponent {
    @ViewChild('container') container: ElementRef;

    //...

    private scrollToBottom() {
        this.container.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.container.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
    }
}
```

I hope, this helped.

Best,

Junus

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding an alternate solution which isn't quite as clean, but at least it works for now:

```
... implements AfterViewChecked
...
ngAfterViewChecked()
{
    let d = document.querySelector('.cdiv');
    if(d)
    {
      d.scrollTop = d.scrollHeight;
    }
}
```